# Fetching in a summary table MIN, MAX, AVERAGE for a specific data and AVERAGE for another data present in each worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

How do I reduce manual work in excel without VBA code - just use of functions formulas to fetch into a summary table the output of MIN, MAX, AVERAGE for a specific data set (and one more AVERAGE on another dataset) in consecutive worksheets of a workbook. The data will be different in each worksheet. The summary represents the cycle time minimum, maximum and averages (and yield% average) of rubber batches being produced in a factory over time. There are approximately 50 different rubber products, so 50 worksheets in the workbook. I have provided sample workbook alongwith the output desired in the link attached. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Cb9eFBIMxq6zyw7bPd1Zetdews7JlX9W/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=107602068659746725053&rtpof=true&sd=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to get the Worksheet names with formula in the Table?
If yes, try this method:

1. Open the Workbook- go to `Formula`- `Name Manager`- `New`- enter `Sheetname` and the formula `=GET.WORKBOOK(1)`:

[image]

2. Enter the formula to get the Worksheet Names:

> =INDEX(MID(Sheetname,FIND("]",Sheetname)+1,30),ROW(A1))&T(NOW())

[image]

Comment: Thank you. With the successive sheet names of the workbook in column A displayed, can we go a step further to go into each worksheet and use a formula on a specific set of cells and return the value in column B? Thanks.